# Keeping a UITabbarController visible in every view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an app with a custom UITabBarController that contains five view controllers. Within each of these view controllers, other view controllers can be accessed. Ideally, I would like my custom UITabBarController to appear in each ViewController-regardless on whether or not the view controller originates directly from the tabbar.

I **think** this can be accomplished using a Navigation Controller within each of the original five view controllers, however, is there a way to just add the custom UITabBarController to each view controller? I tried doing this by the following ways in my `viewDidLoad` methods:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
tabbarController = appDelegate.tabBarController;

tabbarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:tabbarController.view];
```

but I get a bad_access in my app delegate when I run the code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you present these "other view controllers" from the view controllers in your tab bar controller?

Comment: Indeed, using `UINavigationController` as the root controller for each tab will give you what you want. Is there any particular reason you don't want to use them ?

Comment: by using: [self presentModalViewController: myviewController];

Comment: @Mutix mainly since the structure of the app is complete and I don't want to redo it. I was hoping to just be able to add the tab bars.

Comment: Changing your code to use navigation controllers should be rather trivial and quick. I will post an answer with example code for you

Comment: That would be awesome...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly stated, using 'UINavigationController's as root controllers of each tab will achieve what you are trying to do.

Here is an example of how to easily setup your tabbar with navigation controllers:

```
- (void)setupTabBar {

    // Create nav-controller for local use
    UINavigationController *localNavController;

    // New tabbar controller and array to contain the view controllers
    UITabBarController * theTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];


    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Setup the view controllers for the different tabs
     *-------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    // Root view controller for Tab 1
    UIViewController *vc;

    vc = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];
    localNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    localNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    localNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Tab1";

    // Add navigation controller to the local vc array (1 of 4)
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavController];


    // Root view controller for Tab 2
    vc = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    localNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    localNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    localNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Tab2";

    // Add navigation controller to the local vc array (2 of 4)
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavController];


    // Root view controller for Tab 3
    vc = [[ViewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController3" bundle:nil];
    localNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    localNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    localNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Tab3";

    // Add navigation controller to the local vc array (3 of 4)
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavController];


    // Root view controller for Tab 4
    vc = [[ViewController4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController4" bundle:nil];
    localNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    localNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    localNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Tab4";

    // Add navigation controller to the local vc array (4 of 4)
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavController];


    // Point the tab bar controllers view controller array to the array
    // of view controllers we just populated
    theTabBarController.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;

    self.tabBarController = theTabBarController;

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

    ...
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Your AppDelegate should have one TabBarController. This TabBarController holds an array of ViewControllers (`tabBarController.viewControllers`).
These ViewControllers should be UINavigation Controllers.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UINavigationController* navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstOfYourControllers;
    UINavigationController* navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sencondOfYourViewControllers;
    UINavigationController* navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:andSoOn;
    UINavigationController* navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:andSoOn;
    UINavigationController* navController5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:andSoOn;

    NSArray* viewControllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1, navController2, navController3, navController4, navController5, nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllerArray;


    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

}

Do not present your NavigationControllers modally. They will be presented on top of your TabBarController and the TabBarController won't be visible anymore. Do also not try to present a TabBarController in a NavigationController.